# Angular JS Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular1.6

I am facing an issue of [ngRepeat:dupes].

```js
systemService.getAllSystemSettings().then(
  function (obj) {
    $scope.project.meta.franchise = obj.find(item => item.keyword === "Program");
    console.log($scope.project.meta.franchise);
    $scope.project.meta.franchise = $scope.project.meta.franchise['keywordValue'].split(';');
    console.log($scope.project.meta.franchise);
    return $scope.project.meta.franchise);
  });
```

in my HTML page :

```html
<select class="form-control" ng-model="project.meta.franchise" ng-disabled="readOnlyUser">
  <option ng-repeat="option in project.meta.franchise" value="{{option}}">{{option}}</option>
</select>
```

Output in console :

```js
{ keyword: "Program", keywordValue: "test_abc;abc_&xyz;efg_&_hij"
}
[
  "test_abc",
  "abc_&xyz",
  "efg_&_hij"
]
```

error in console:

[image]

Please help me out in solving I tried putting track by $ index but no solution with that too. By using $track by it does not show the list in options. ThankYou in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the value of the ng-model to project.franchise in your HTML code. Below is the code I applied and it worked for me:-

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="project.franchise" ng-disabled="readOnlyUser">
  <option ng-repeat="option in project.meta.franchise)" value="{{option}}">{{option}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to make a custom unique index like this

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="project.meta.franchise)" ng-disabled="readOnlyUser">
   <option ng-repeat="option in project.meta.franchise track by ($index + ':' + option)" value="{{option}}">{{option}}</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: With this it gives me error when I select it does not  show any thing in dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Try giving multiple = 'true' in your HTML select statement. Please refer to [Davis Ford's](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/366) post in GitHub regarding the same.